# Applying a specific format to TableColumn

Tags: .net, openxml

I am trying to create a `SpreadsheetDocument` with a `Table` based on a custom `TableStyleInfo`:

```
stylesheet.DifferentialFormats = new DifferentialFormats
(
    new DifferentialFormat // 0 - TableStyleValues.WholeTable
    {
        Font = new Font { FontName = new FontName { Val = "Tahoma" } },
        Fill = new Fill { PatternFill = new PatternFill { PatternType = PatternValues.None } }
        Alignment = new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.General }
    },
    new DifferentialFormat // 1 - TableStyleValues.HeaderRow
    {
        Fill = new Fill
        {
            PatternFill = new PatternFill
            {
                PatternType = PatternValues.Solid,
                BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Rgb = "FFF5F5F5" }
            }
        },
        Alignment = new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center }
    },
    new DifferentialFormat // 2 - TableStyleValues.SecondRowStripe
    {
        Fill = new Fill
        {
            PatternFill = new PatternFill
            {
                PatternType = PatternValues.Solid,
                BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Rgb = "FFF5F5F5" }
            }
        }
    },
    new DifferentialFormat // 3 - Date
    {
        NumberingFormat = new NumberingFormat
        {
            NumberFormatId = 164,
            FormatCode = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }
    }
) { Count = 4 };

stylesheet.TableStyles = new TableStyles(new TableStyle
(
    new TableStyleElement { Type = TableStyleValues.WholeTable, FormatId = 0 },
    new TableStyleElement { Type = TableStyleValues.HeaderRow, FormatId = 1 },
    new TableStyleElement { Type = TableStyleValues.SecondRowStripe, FormatId = 2 }
) { Name = "TableStyle", Table = true, Count = 3 });

tableDefPart.Table = new Table
{
    HeaderRowCount = 1,
    TableStyleInfo = new TableStyleInfo
    {
        Name = ((TableStyle)stylesheet.TableStyles.FirstChild).Name,
        ShowRowStripes = true
    },
    TableColumns = new TableColumns
    (
        new TableColumn
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name"
        },
        new TableColumn
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Date",
            DataFormatId = 3 // no effect
        }
    ) { Count = 2 };
};
```

My `DifferentialFormats` collection includes 4 items, the first 3 of which are referenced from respective `TableStyleElement` entries, while the last one is referenced from the second `TableColumn` definition. The latter does not seem to work. It works if I apply the style to, say, `SecondRowStripe`, so the formatting itself is correct.

Can anyone explain what the `TableColumn.DataFormatId` should point to and what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

P.S. Setting `TableColumn.DataCellStyle` to a named `CellStyle` index does not work either, so appling a custom format to a `TableColumn` seems to not be honored at all.

Description of the fields:

*DataFormatId*

> A zero based integer index into the differential formatting records  in the styleSheet indicating which format to apply to the data area of this column. This formatting shall also apply to cells on the insert row for this column. The spreadsheet should fail to load if this index is out of bounds.

*DataCellStyle*

> A string representing the name of the cell style that is applied to the cells in the data area of this table column. If this string is missing or does not correspond to the name of a cell style, then the data cell style specified by the current table style should be applied. This cell style should get precedence over the dataCellStyle defined by the table.